# jQuery mousemove animation for sliding long URLs into view

Tags: jquery, css, animation, mousemove

I want to have the span move so that when you are at the right side of `div.url`, you are all the way at the end of the `span` inside the `div.url`.

When you are at the left side of `div.url`, you are at the left side of the `span`.

Hopefully that makes sense. I don't want there to be any visible blank space after the end of the url...it should match up with right-side of `div.url`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/chovy/FcSNw/

ps: bonus points if you can apply a bell curve to the sliding so the mid-point of the url is the fastest acceleration.

```
function log(m){
    ( console.log && console.log(m) );
}
$(function(){
    $(".url").mousemove(function(e){
        var $targ = $(e.currentTarget)
            , $span = $targ.find('span')
            , offset = e.pageX - $targ.offset().left
        ;

        log($targ);
        log(offset);
        $span.css({ left: -offset });
    });
});

table, td { border: 1px solid gray; }
td, .url { width: 300px; }
.url { overflow-x: hidden; position: relative; }
.url, .url span { padding: 0; height: 20px;  line-height: 20px; }
.url span { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; display: block; white-space:nowrap; }
table { margin-left: 200px; }

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td><div class="url"><span>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div class="url"><span>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div class="url"><span>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div class="url"><span>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div class="url"><span>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div class="url"><span>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js</span></div></td></tr>
        <tr><td><div class="url"><span>https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js</span></div></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fix, with accelerated scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/aw2A9/

```
$(function(){
    $(".url").mousemove(function(e){
        var $targ = $(e.currentTarget)
        , $span = $targ.find('span')
        , offset = e.pageX - $targ.offset().left
        ;

        var parentwidth = $span.parent().width()
        , overflow = $span.width() - parentwidth
        , scrollmargin = parentwidth * 0.20 // add margin for scroll area
        , scrollwidth = parentwidth - ( scrollmargin * 2 )
        , scrolloffset = Math.min( Math.max(0, offset-scrollmargin ),scrollwidth)
        , ratio = 0.5 - Math.cos(( scrolloffset / scrollwidth ) * Math.PI )/2
        , newpos = overflow * ratio;

        if ( overflow > 0 ) { $span.css({ left: -newpos }); };

    });
});
```

The extra calculations with scrollmargin, scrollwidth and scrolloffset are so that it doesn't scroll when you are near the edges. The non-scrolling area is set at 20% of width in this example.

Comment: This is great. Can you explain in layman's terms how the acceleration works?

Comment: If you look at a [cosine wave](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cosine.svg) you can see how it starts off gradual, becomes steep in the middle, then flattens out. It moves between -1 and 1, but we add 1 and divide by 2 to get the right number range between 0 and 1. We now multiply it by our actual cursor position offset to get an acecelerated offset based on the cosine wave

Comment: To clarify, without the acceleration, we would say "the cursor is x% through the element, so show x% of the overflow". With acceleration we say "the cursor is x% through the element, so go x% along the cosine wave, get it's height at that point ( as a value between 0 and 1 rather than -1 to 1 ) and use that as our percent instead.